# Which programming languages, other than C++, support operator overloading?

Tags: programming-languages, operator-overloading

I know C++.

Anything other?

Comment: Try finding the answer using Google.

Comment: What do you mean 'do not accept C++'? How is it related to the question?

Comment: Why is this tagged as linux ? Looking for linux only programming languages?

Comment: "Which programming languages, other than C++, support operator overloading?" is probably a better formulation.

Comment: 2 Tom: I'm not interested in languages with bad support in linux, like C#

Comment: @vitaly.v.ch: C# support in Linux is decent. Think mono project. And that should be specified in a question. Tags are just for searching convenience.

Comment: 2 EFraim: "decent" is too indefinitely. I'm interested in something near C/C++/Lisp

Comment: 2 aioobe:

Thanks, It's good idea

Comment: That's a lot of typing effort just to get a link to wikipedia...

Answer (score -4):

I'm amused thinking about it.  Any C compiler for example, must tell between an `int *c;` and `double d = (int) f * (float) g;`.  In the former case, * indicates c is a pointer to int while in the latter case it is a multiplication operator.  Though not exported outside the compiler itself, C appears to have operator overloading feature.  C++ exported it outside the compiler?

I am sure other languages like Java should have some mechanism to tell + or * or such operators when they are used between various combinations and permutations of the types of the operands.