# Change sign + for a String that does the same action (like Operator overloading)

Tags: java, string, operands

There are 2 variables and I need to sum them. But instead using the + sign I'd like to change it for a String.

```
double var1 = 1;
double var2 = 2;
String sign = "+"; 

double variable3 = var1 sign var2;
```

I'd like to sum them using the "sign" instead, But i don't know if there's a way to do this.

Comment: Java doesn't support operator overloading. Have a look for more information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865526/which-programming-languages-other-than-c-support-operator-overloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't allow "Operator overloading", see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686699/operator-overloading-in-java) for some info.

But, you can use a method to handle the `sign` like this:

```
double handleOperation(String sign, double int1, double int2)
{
    if(sign.equals("+")) {
        return int1 + int2;
    }
    else if(sign.equals("-")) {
        return int1 - int2;
    }
    // others

    return 0;
}

double var1 = 1;
double var2 = 2;
String sign = "+"; 

double variable3 = handleOperation(sign, var1, var2);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can't override operators like in C++. You can override only methods.